# Load more posts in the same category - WordPress + Ajax + Timber

Tags: ajax, wordpress, timber

I use Timber with WordPress.

I'm trying to create a list of posts with a `"Load more posts"` button.

I would like to display 10 posts of the same category and to load 10 others posts of the same category when the user click on the button `"Load more posts"`

All work fine when there is no distinction between categories. The button `"Load more posts"` work fine. 10 posts are display.

But when I try to display posts in the same category when I click on the button `"Load more posts"`. No post are display. What's wrong with category ?

Can I have some help please ?

### archive.php

```
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;

$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category__in' => array($category),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => 1,
    'has_password' => FALSE
));
```

### script.js

```
function load_more_news() {
    var page = 1;

    $(document).on('click', '#load-more-news', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        page++;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                'action' : 'get_news',
                'get_page' : page
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if($('<div></div>').html(data).find('.archive__item.ended').size() > 0) $('#load-more-news').parents('.cta').remove();
                else $('#load-more-news').parents('.cta').show();
                $('#archive__list').append(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

### functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_news', 'get_news' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_news', 'get_news' );
function get_news() {
    global $post;

    $context = Timber::get_context();
    $context['get_page'] = empty($_POST['get_page']) ? 1 : $_POST['get_page'];

    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category = $category[0]->cat_ID;

    $context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category__in' => array($category),
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $context['get_page'],
        'has_password' => FALSE
    ));
    $count = count(Timber::get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category__in' => array($category)
    )));

    if($count <= $context['get_page'] * 10) $context['ended'] = 'ended';

    Timber::render( 'bloc_news.twig', $context );

    die();
}
```

### archive.twig

```
<section class="archive">
    <p class="archive__title h-headline text-size-l">In the same thematic</p>
    <div id="archive__list" class="archive__list">
        <article class="post">
            ...
        </article>
    </div>
</section>

{% if posts|length >= 10 %}
<section class="cta">
    <a href="#" id="load-more-news">
        <p class="cta__text">Load more posts</p>
    </a>
</section>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, it's difficult to understand you, but it seems to me that your problem is that you are pointing all the time to a global post

```
function get_news() {
    global $post;
```

You need to explicitly request the category what does this mean, I will explain

You need to transfer id categories to the server, and not use global $post.
The algorithm is as follows:

**1)** return the category id to the button on the client

```
<button data-cid="{category_id}">Load more posts</button>
```

or somewhere in the parent element of the category

```
<div class="category" data-cid="<?php print $category_id; ?>">
        <!-- 10 posts -->
        <article class="post">...</article>
        ....
        <button>Load more posts</button>
</div>
```

**2)** After clicking on the button, get this СID (category id) and send it to the server

```
function load_more_news() {
    var page = 1;

    $(document).on('click', '#load-more-news', function(e) {
        let $el = $(this); // of e.currentTarget;
        e.preventDefault();
        page++;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                'action': 'get_news',
                'get_page': page,
                'cid': $el.data('cid') // CID or $el.parents('[data-cid]').data('cid');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if ($('<div></div>').html(data).find('.archive__item.ended').size() > 0) $('#load-more-news').parents('.cta').remove();
                else $('#load-more-news').parents('.cta').show();
                $('#archive__list').append(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**3)** use this on server instead of global post

```
'category__in' => array($_POST['cid'])
```

**Addition:**

What means: when I click on the button "Load more posts". **No post are display**. ?

1. What is returned from the server?
2. Check what you get with ::get_posts()?
3. Why don't you just use [get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) of native wordpress api function ?

Check and debug all data that comes to the server and returns

Organize your code:
1.) send ajax url to the client

```
wp_register_script('your-script', PLUG_URL.'your-script.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(  PLUG_DIR.'your-script.js' ), true);
   
wp_localize_script('your-script', 'glb',
    array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    )
);
```

and use it and use this instead of hardcore with $.post function of jquery (recommended)

```
let payload = {
  page: 2
}
$.post(glb.ajax_url, {action: 'get_news', data: payload, function(e) {
 ....
});
```

2.) Check what comes to the server

```
function get_news() {
     wp_send_json($_POST['data']);
}
$.post(glb.ajax_url, {action: 'get_news', data: payload, function(e) {
     console.log(e); // {page: 2}
});

function get_news() { 
    if(!isset($_POST['data'])) {
      wp_send_json_error();
}
$data = $_POST['data'];

$posts = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category__in'    => [$category],
        'orderby'     => 'date',
        'order'       => 'DESC',
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'paged' => $data['page']
    ));
  wp_send_json($posts);
}
$.post(glb.ajax_url, {action: 'get_news', data: payload, function(e) {
   console.log(e); // ??? 
});
```

Make checks, return data and look for where you have a "hole"

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try. I update my question because you are right it was not very clear. I add the code of the file archive.twig

Comment: I added an addition to the answer for you